# Write current date/time to a file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I am trying to use a shell script to write the current date and time to a file. Here is what I have so far

`echo "$(date)" >> //home/user/Desktop/Scripts/Date Logs/datelog.txt`

It will say it completed but nothing is printed to the file after it is run.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `date >> //home/user/Desktop/Scripts/Date Logs/datelog.txt`.

Like i tried in my system :-

`date > /tmp/date.txt`.
And file contains `Wed Apr 5 09:27:37 IST 2017`.

[Edit]  There are difference between >>(appending to the file) and >(Create the new file)

Edit:- As suggested by chepner, you can directly redirect the o/p of date command to file using `date >> /tmp/date.txt`.

Comment: I got it to work for 2 tries but it was appending to new file created in the Scripts directory under the file name Date.txt, figured it was caused by the space in the Date Logs directory name, changed it still no go. 

Date.txt output
Tue Apr  4 22:35:29 CDT 2017 Logs/datelog.txt
Tue Apr  4 22:41:16 CDT 2017 Logs/datelog.txt
date Logs/datelog.txt
date Logs/datelog.txt

datelog.txt output (AfterChangingDirectoryName)
date
date
date
date

My exact code at the moment getting me the output in datelog.txt file. 

'echo 'date' >> //home/coblere/Desktop/Scripts/DateLogs/datelog.txt'

Comment: i see in some of the file date is coming, note you need to use the `` symbol to enclose the date command. not the ''. first one is called back-tick and its on the same key in mac where ~ symbol is present.

Comment: Ahhhh! I mistook that simple for the simple single quote Like so 'date' not `date` now it works like a charm! Thanks for you help!

Comment: There's no need to use `echo`; just redirect the output of `date` directly: `date > /tmp/date.txt`