# Writing date in a log file using Git hooks with Windows batch

Tags: windows, git, shell

I have the idea of using Git hooks with the intention of updating the date (and "time" later on) in a log file every time I do commit, with using the following commands in the `pre-commit` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo %date% >> log.txt
```

But it doesn't work as I expect, it writes exactly the same `%date%` instead of something `04/23/2020`.

Secondly, is it wise to use Git hook scripts to do such a thing? I guess I will next have an infinite committing problem as every commit will update the file. What other options do I have to do a basic update in a text file on every push or commit?

Comment: You used tag `[batch-file]` but `#!/bin/sh` which is not batch file but a shell script. Could you please fix your text or tags?

Comment: I fixed the tag thanks for pointing out.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43221504/7976758 and https://linux.die.net/man/1/date. `date +%Y/%m/%d >> log.txt`

Comment: @phd thank you so much that is what I was looking for !!

Comment: Well, `echo %date%` is Windows Command Prompt and Windows batch file syntax...

Comment: I guess I didn't pay enough attention to the difference of the two terms, which led me to make a wrong google search, but now I see the difference, thanks both for your help.